# Excel Countif function with selecting discrete range of cells

Tags: excel, excel-formula

How to write  Countif function with selecting discrete range of cells, I mean the range cannot be written as (A:B), they are not adjacent.

I wrote the following function, but it is showing me **#Value!**

COUNTIF((**F7,I7**),">0")

Answer (score 0):

Use `Countifs()` function as  following

```
=COUNTIFS(F7,">0",I7,">0")
```

Answer (score 0):

## COUNTIF Versions

```
=SUM(COUNTIF(F7,">0"),COUNTIF(H7,">0"))
=IF(OR(COUNTIF(F7,">0"),COUNTIF(H7,">0")),1,0)
=IF(AND(COUNTIF(F7,">0"),COUNTIF(H7,">0")),1,0)
```

1. If both cells are greater than 0, the result is 2.
   If either one of the cells is greater than 0, the result is 1.
   If no cell is greater than 0,the result is 0.
2. If both cells are greater than 0, the result is 1.
   If either one of the cells is greater than 0, the result is 1.
   If no cell is greater than 0, the result is 0.
3. If both cells are greater than 0, the result is 1.
   If only one of the cells is greater than 0, the result is 0.
   If no cell is greater than 0, the result is 0.